# Can't draw the epipolar lines in camera calibration and 3D- reconstruction using opencv & python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, opencv3.1

After I have generated the Fundamental and Essential Matrix from Camera calibration, I am trying to get the Epipolar lines, and draw them in my images to test the Matrix I have generated, following this [python-opencv tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html)

Here is the code for impelementing the drawing epipolar lines function:

```
    def drawlines(img1,img2,lines,pts1,pts2):
        ''' img1 - image on which we draw the epilines for the points in img2
            lines - corresponding epilines 
        '''
        r,c = img1.shape
        img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        for r,pt1,pt2 in zip(lines,pts1,pts2):
            color = tuple(np.random.randint(0,255,3).tolist())
            x0,y0 = map(int, [0, -r[2]/r[1] ])
            x1,y1 = map(int, [c, -(r[2]+r[0]*c)/r[1] ])
            img1 = cv2.line(img1, (x0,y0), (x1,y1), color,1)
            img1 = cv2.circle(img1,tuple(pt1),5,color,-1)
            img2 = cv2.circle(img2,tuple(pt2),5,color,-1)
        return img1,img2
```

but when I run the following code to generate the epipolar lines, I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "FundMat.py", line 124,
>   in          img5,img6 = drawlines(img1,img2,lines1,pts1,pts2)    File
>   "FundMat.py",   line 21, in drawlines
>         img1 = cv2.circle(img1,tuple(pt1),5,color,-1)
>      TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

So, why I got this error and how to solve it?

Comment: You only included a version-specific tag for OpenCV instead of the general `opencv` tag which means your question got lost in the abyss. Answerers on Stack subscribe to certain tags so they can easily find questions, and version specific ones are far less popular. Feel free to tag with version specific tags if you feel the issue might be related to the version, but always include the general one for exposure so more people actually see your question. This is why no one answered this question though it is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your points are in a different format than OpenCV wants. Your `pt1` and `pt2` probably look something like `np.array([[x, y]])`, but look what the tuple looks like when you cast it:

```
>>> pt1 = np.array([[50, 50]])
>>> tuple(pt1)
(array([50, 50]),)
```

This is a tuple with a single element, instead of two items like you expect. Obviously for drawing, it wants a tuple with length 2 (namely, the `x` and `y` coordinates). Hence the error; the inner function expects *two* arguments but only one value was inside your tuple. To demonstrate:

```
>>> pt1 = np.array([[50, 50]])
>>> cv2.circle(img, tuple(pt1), 5, 255, -1)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "...", line 10, in <module>  
>     cv2.circle(img, tuple(pt1), 5, 255, -1) TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
> ```

Instead, this is what you want the tuple to look like:

```
>>> tuple(pt1[0])
(50, 50)
```

Supposing you want to be able to handle points passed in either format, just reshape the point first. Either way you only have two values in the `pt1` or `pt2` arrays, so reshaping won't affect it. For e.g. you could use `flatten()` from numpy:

```
>>> tuple(pt1.flatten())
(50, 50)
```

And this should fix your issue.

```
>>> pt1 = np.array([[50, 50]])
>>> cv2.circle(img, tuple(pt1.flatten()), 5, 255, -1)
>>>
```